# How to calculate angle between two vectors in 3D with clockwise or counter clockwise notation?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, 3d, angle

If I have vectors a and b sharing a common point of intersection then I know how to calculate angle between them by using the formula for dot product. But whether b lies to the right or left of a if I am moving along a can not be gotten from this.

What would be the easiest way to find out whether b lies left or right of a?

Comment: what do you mean? left or right relative to what?

Comment: Or clockwise-counterclockwise. I said left-right to represent if we are moving along a and then take turn to go in the direction of b (like in a road) then will it be a left turn or right turn. Dot product angle doesn't give this information

Comment: @Rafa: Take your right hand and make the victory sign (index and middle finger as a "V"). If the palm is facing you, then the index finger is to the right of the middle finger. If you turn your hand so that the palm faces away from you, then the index finger is to the left of the middle finger. That means the answer if a vector is to the left or right of another vector depends on the viewpoint, and so the question has no real answer.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What I really wanted to know is if we consistently look from one side only following a convention then if there is any way to know if the angle is clockwise or anticlockwise. 
As in case of your example, if we have three fingers out (index, middle and ring) then ring finger and index fingers are at different sides of middle finger even though the absolute angles might be the same. So how can I get theta and -theta as angles between them from a mathematical formula/calculation? 
If it is still unclear I will try to explain in some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for "left" and "right" to be defined you need to have a sense of turning direction. Generally this requires not only to a sense of the "forward" direction given by the vector $\mathbf a,$ but also to some sense of which way is "up."

If the vectors are constrained to lie in a plane and we have a viewpoint from which we can look "down" on the plane then left and right are intuitively clear.
To tell whether the vector $\mathbf b$ is angled to the left or right of 
$\mathbf a,$
construct a vector by rotating $\mathbf a$ ninety degrees to the right,
giving you a new vector $\mathbf v$ perpendicular to (and pointing to the right of) $\mathbf a.$

If you have the components of $\mathbf a$ in the usual $x,y$ coordinates, that is, $\mathbf a = (a_x,a_y),$ with the usual orientation of the axes, then you could write 
$\mathbf v = (a_y, -a_x).$

Now take the dot product $\mathbf b \cdot \mathbf v.$
If it is positive, $\mathbf b$ points to the right of $\mathbf a$; if negative,
$\mathbf b$ points to the left of $\mathbf a.$

Comment: Thanks! I am assuming **v** has to be in the same plane as **a** and **b** ? How exactly can I calculate **v** in a simple manner?

Comment: I added an example of a rotated vector.

Answer (score 5):

As David K and others pointed out, in order to distinguish “left” and “right” you need some reference. In a comment you describe consistently looking “down” onto the plane in which the vectors lie. Mathematically, you can specify this by choosing a fixed vector $\mathbf u$ that specifies the “up” direction relative to this plane. Once you have this, then you can distinguish the two rotation directions by examining the sign of $$\det\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf a&\mathbf b&\mathbf u\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf a\times\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf u.$$ If this value is positive, then the three vectors (in that order) form a right-handed set; if negative, then it’s left-handed. If it’s zero, then $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ must either be parallel or antiparallel, so the rotation direction is ambiguous, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use cross product. The sign of cross product of a and b will let you know if the angle is clockwise or counter clockwise.

Comment: The cross product of two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ is another vector. What do you mean by its sign?